# uploading image to facebook album, must accept every image

Tags: android, facebook

When I'm uploading images to my Facebook albums everything used to work fine, and the images got posted on the timeline automatically. However, now when I upload images I need to go to the album and accept the image. I get the following information

```
"Photos below are uploaded by another application, so you must accept them."
```

I don't know why it stopped working, its like the application forgot my permissions. I have tried to remove the app from both android and Facebook page. Nothing seems to work. I'm using the following permissions.

```
facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "user_photos", "publish_checkins",
                "publish_stream", "publish_actions" },
```

edit: The album I'm uploading to is the one my app automatically created.